# Ignore first four characters from tibble in R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a Tibble from which I want to remove first four letters. I am unable to do it. I tried `substr()` and `substring()` but they tend to merge all the rows.

Here's my data:

```
dput(a)
structure(list(value = c("ABC-EFGH-1234IJK-45K", "IJK-LOKK-TIU"
)), .Names = "value", row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Expected Output:

```
"EFGH-1234IJK-45K"
"LOKK-TIU"
```

Here's what I tried:

**Try #1:**

```
substr(as.data.frame.array(a),4,nchar(as.data.frame.array(a)))
```

but the output is:

```
"t(`c(\"ABC-EFGH-IJK\", \"IJK-LOKK-TIU\")` = 1:2)"
```

**Try#2:**

```
stringr::str_sub((as.data.frame.array(a)),start = 4, end = nchar((as.data.frame.array(a))))
```

The output is:

```
"t(`c(\"ABC-EFGH-IJK\", \"IJK-LOKK-TIU\")` = 1:2)"
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Why on earth `as.data.frame.array`?

Comment: don't you mean: `substr(a$value, 5, nchar(a$value))`?

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to convert it to atomic vector. Sorry about this.

Comment: You don't need to convert anything, simply `substring(a$value, 5)` will do

Comment: or `sub('.{4}', '', a$value)` or... or... or...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
substr(a$value,5,nchar(a$value))
```